# Unset variables and move on to the next line if condition not met

Tags: shell, ksh

I need someone to help me with the below requirement.

I have 4 variables derived from while statement (var1, var2, var3, var4).

Under this while loop, I have an if loop to check (var4) against a condition and to write to output file.

My requirement is if var4 doesn't meet the if condition, the variables (var1,var2,var3 including var4) shouldn't be included in the output file.

I tried to use `unset ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)`, but it is not working.

My if loop:

```
if [! -z "var4"]
then
  mynew=`echo "var4"`
else 
  unset ($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4)
fi
```

Comment: Can you refer my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues in your code**

First, the assignment

```
mynew=`echo "var4"`
```

is an expensive (as it involves a subshell) and indirect way of saying

```
mynew="$var4"
```

which is very simple and straight forward.

Second, we need to pass variable names to `unset`, rather than the values.  Hence:

```
unset $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4
```

is wrong, unless you want to unset the variables whose names are contained in `var1` through `var4`.  With `unset $var1`, shell will interpret the value contained in `var1` as the name of the variable to be unset.  If the value is empty, unset will not take any action and it is considered normal.

**Solution**

With the above corrections, you could rewrite your `if` block like this:

```
if [[ "$var4" ]]; then
  # var4 is set
  mynew="$var4"
else
  unset var1 var2 var3 var4
fi
```

If the actions in `if` and `else` are a single statement as in your example, you could the write above `if` in a compact form using `&&` and `||` constructs as seen in @Inian's answer.

---

**More info**

`[[ "$var4" ]]` could also be written as:

```
[[ ! -z "$var4" ]] # $var4 is not of zero length
```

or

```
[[ -n "$var4" ]]   # $var4 is not empty
```

Comment: Thank you codeforester, not only for the solution but also for the explanation.

Comment: Glad it helped @Sunny1985!  [What to do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi Codeforester, Can you help me with another thing,

Comment: Can you make changes to the condition like, If var4 is less than 50 days of current date

Comment: Comments are not meant for asking new questions.  Please post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single line as,

```
[ ! -z "$var4" ] && read mynew <<<"${var4}" || unset var1 var2 var3 var4
# Checking if '$var4' is not empty
# Storing var4 variable value in 'mynew'
# If empty un-setting all the variables in one shot
```

(or) just the below should be fine

```
[ ! -z "$var4" ] && mynew="${var4}" || unset var1 var2 var3 var4
```

Comment: @codeforester: Not really kind of overlooked there!